# setuptools not available - error when installing Python package with pip

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip, package

I'm trying to install the `importlib` package using `pip3`, but I'm getting an error that says **"Can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available in the build environment."** How can I fix this error and successfully install the importlib package?

```bash
mrichardsonr1@penguin:~$ pip3 install importlib
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting importlib
  Using cached importlib-1.0.4.zip (7.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have uninstalled pip, setuptools, updated everything reinstalled everything, nothing works. I am running this on Linux x86_64 container on ChromeOS. I am using the latest version of `setuptools` which is what I was told could be causing this.

```bash
mrichardsonr1@penguin:~$ pip3 install setuptools
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (65.6.3)
```

As far as I know everything else is up to date. No clue why I am getting this error, and it's not just when installing this package I had the same issue trying to install the `ping` package.

Comment: this could help - https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/importlib/

Installation package `importlib` is only for Python 2.7, you cannot install it with `pip3`.

In Python 3 `importlib` became a package from the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html . You don't need to install it separately; once you've installed Python3 and the standard library the package is available for import. To check from the command line:

```bash
$ python3 -c "import importlib"
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, but I am still having issues running Cura with the `--no-sandbox` tag `mrichardsonr1./cura.AppImage --no-sandbox
PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py:499: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses` It just says that and then nothing happens. I would like to say that what you said seems to have done "something" because no errors occured but it didnt give output: `mrichardsonr1@penguin:~$ python3 -c "import importlib"
mrichardsonr1@penguin:~$ `

Comment: @OrbitalMartian 1. `python3 -c "import importlib"` is not supposed to produce output; it show there is no error/exception; to have some debugging output you can do ` python3 -c "import importlib; print(importlib)"` 2. "*DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated…*" is just a warning; though my advice is to fix the application (if it's your code) or report it to the authors (if it isn't).

Comment: Running python3 -c "import importlib" and trying to install the ping library, I got this error: `Collecting ping
  Using cached ping-0.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-lb8bdn1p/ping_c43c1b90fca74c33bbfdd4634e424644/setup.py", line 23, in <module>`

Comment: @OrbitalMartian That's a completely different question, it must be asked separately. But [first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) try [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ping).

Comment: I know it is, but I'm not trying to find a solution for `ping` here I am just showing an example that the `setuptools` is still not working. Running the `python3 -c "import importlib; print(importlib)"` produces: `mrichardsonr1@penguin:~$ python3 -c "import importlib; print(importlib)"
<module 'importlib' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py'>` And about the application, It is a 3D printing slicer that is full supported by linux

Comment: @OrbitalMartian I don't see it's related to the question. Please create a new question and show the entire traceback, formatted. For full error message try `pip install -vvv ping`

Comment: Thanks for the headstart. I'm sure I'll figure out whats wrong soon!